# Highcharts zoom programatically

Tags: highcharts

I have to zoom into highcharts programmatically.

There is a method to zoom in to X-Axis and Y-Axis independently using

```
xAxis.setExtremes(100, 200); 
yAxis.setExtremes(100, 200);
```

Is there a way where I can zoom into highcharts with just one function instead of calling two?

I have heard of `chart.zoom()` but am not sure about the parameters it takes.

Answer (score 0):

There is `chart.zoom` method, but it is internal and it is not a part of official API.

You can check how it works here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/49a925eb98237f8d303a3fe90431ea2a8bf2e9b3/ts/Core/Chart/Chart.ts#L3515

However, using anything else for zooming will still use setExtremes under the hood. If you need a single function, just create it:

```
function zoomChart(chart, x1, x2, y1, y2) {
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(x1, x2, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(y1, y2);
}

// function call
zoomChart(chart, 4, 8, 2, 10);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82seLczw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: can you provide an example of the parameters to be passed to the zoom function

Comment: Here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/49a925eb98237f8d303a3fe90431ea2a8bf2e9b3/ts/Core/Pointer.ts#L2096 is a type definition for the parameter. And after manual zoom here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tfLxn9gd/ is a sample log.